# Hide/show menuitem in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyjs

I want to hide and show a menuItem when a user check a box. I used `useShinyjs()` and `renderMenu()` function but once the menuItem is shown, I cannot hide it again by unchecking the box.

This is what I did :

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)

header <- dashboardHeader(title = "my app")

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(id="menu",
              menuItem("Tab 1",tabName = "tab1", icon = icon("question")),
              menuItemOutput("another_tab"),
              menuItem("Tab 2", tabName = "tab2", icon = icon("home"))
              )
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "tab1",
            useShinyjs(),
            checkboxInput("somevalue", "Check me", FALSE)
    )
  )
)

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$another_tab <- renderMenu({
    if(input$somevalue == TRUE)
      menuItem("My tab", tabName = "tab3", icon = icon("cogs"))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

How can we hide the menuItem again ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way to do it is

```
  output$another_tab <- renderMenu({
    if(input$somevalue == TRUE) {
      menuItem("My tab", tabName = "tab3", icon = icon("cogs"))
    }else shinyjs::hide(selector = "a[data-value='tab3']" )
  })
```

Comment: Your solution with no space holder is much better

Answer (score 1):

You can create an empty `menuItem()`:

```r
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$another_tab <- renderMenu({
    if(input$somevalue == TRUE)
      menuItem("My tab", tabName = "tab3", id="tab3", icon = icon("cogs"))
    else
      menuItem(NULL)
  })
}
```